# How can I get 2nd and third column in tab delim file in bash?

Tags: bash, process, tabs, delimited

I want to use bash to process a tab delimited file. I only need the second column and third to a new file.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

[`cut(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cut) was made expressly for this purpose:

```
cut -f 2-3 input.txt > output.txt
```

Answer (score 15):

Cut is probably the best choice here, second to that is `awk`

```
awk -F"\t" '{print $2 "\t" $3}' input > out
```

Comment: the file had 2 million rows so i guess cut was good...thank you for your help

Comment: `awk` comes in particularly handy when you want to change the order of columns. `cut` can't do that!

Answer (score 3):

expanding on the answer of carl-norum, using only tab  as a delimiter, not all blanks:

```
cut -d$'\t' -f 2-3 input.txt > output.txt
```

don't put a space between d and $