# How to cut 2nd and 3rd column out of a textfile? python

Tags: python, bash, cut, csv

I have a tab-delimited file with lines as such:

```
foo bar bar <tab>x y z<tab>a foo foo
...
```

Imagine 1,000,000 lines, with up to 200 words per line. each word on average of 5-6 characters.

To the 2nd and 3rd column, I can do this:

```
with open('test.txt','r') as infile:
  column23 = [i.split('\t')[1:3] for i in infile]
```

or i could use unix, [How can i get 2nd and third column in tab delim file in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312564/how-can-i-get-2nd-and-third-column-in-tab-delim-file-in-bash)

```
import os
column23 = [i.split('\t') os.popen('cut -f 2-3 test.txt').readlines()]
```

Which is faster? Is there any other way to extract the 2nd and 3rd column?

Comment: Avoid building the `list`, it's very memory hungry

Comment: Why are you splitting in the last example? I **think** that cut will be faster, but you should run a benchmark with smaller test data,

Comment: Do you have a testfile we could use to see which solution is fastest?

Comment: You can time you code with the timeit module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use neither. Unless it proves to be too slow, use the `csv` module, which is far more readable.

```
import csv
with open('test.txt','r') as infile:
    column23 = [ cols[1:3] for cols in csv.reader(infile, delimiter="\t") ]
```

Answer (score 1):

If there can be hundreds of tab-delimited entries per line, and you only want the second and third, then you don't need to [`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) all of them; there is a `maxsplit` parameter you can use that should speed things up:

```
with open('test.txt','r') as infile:
    column23 = [i.split('\t', 3)[1:3] for i in infile]
```

And who knows, maybe a clever regex would even be faster:

```
import re
regex = re.compile("^[^\t\n]*\t([^\t\n]*)\t([^\t\n]*)", re.MULTILINE)
with open('test.txt','r') as infile:
    columns23 = regex.findall(infile.read())
```